# How to keep the user logged in based on jwt token authentication.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frontend

I have an web application written in Java Spring which have authentication based on **jwt token**. I don't know a good approach of how to keep the user logged in after browser closed/restart. My question is: How to use the token auth on front-end side ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store token in `localStorage`. It works similar to cookies but you can access it with javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: What user details I have needed to keep in this localStorage variable, the token and username ?

Comment: Whatever the data that backend needs to verify requests. Also, you will have to make sure that the token is passed around with http requests

Comment: Don't store JWT tokens in localStorage! Use secure cookies. https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens